# Align circles on top

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

What I want to achieve is a bunch of circles that are aligned in a certain way (in this case on top) like you would do it in a program like Adobe Illustrator for example.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var maxCircle = 20;
var y = 0;
var radius = 10;

ctx.translate(500,500);

//Draw January
for (var i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, y, i*radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.rotate(2*Math.PI/maxCircle);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #fff;">

    <canvas id="canvas" width="2000" height="2000" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    </canvas>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

How can I align all my generated circles on one side?

For example align them on one top line?

```
var maxCircle = 20;
var y = 0;
var radius = 10;

ctx.translate(1000,1000);

for (var i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, y, i*radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.rotate(2*Math.PI/maxCircle);
  }
```

Comment: Please explain, your example has all the circles on one corner. Also at least give a runnable example instead of having us create one, to make it more clear what your current code is doing vs what you want it to do. Also how is [what you have related](https://jsfiddle.net/tgmvyq5a/) to what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your circles have an increasing radius. If you want to align them against a top line, then you should better not use `ctx.rotate`: that really does not help to reach that result.

Instead introduce a variable *x* and use the existing *y* to calculate what the centre has to be of every circle:

```js
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var radius = 10;

ctx.translate(10,2); // adjust translation so first circle appears in top-left corner

for (var i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
  x += i*radius;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, i*radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  x += i*radius;
  y += radius;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cvs" width="610" height="180"></canvas>
```